# Rename [downloading] to [download]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/downloading) (200+ Questions) is not different enough from [download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/download) (5000+) to deserve a separate tag.

Comment: Why is this an issue for users?

Comment: If 2 tags mean the same thing, then 1 must go. It may even get confusing, where for example I saw a user use both in one Question.

Comment: There are only [11 questions that are tagged with both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/download+downloading).

Comment: Does that mean it's okay to have 2 tags referring to the same thing? Would you rather these were made synonyms?

Comment: I think it should go. In what case is someone an expert in download but not in downloading?

Comment: +1, would suggest synonym myself if I had sufficient downloading rep.

Comment: Both tags suck.

Comment: @tbodt retagging is not the same as making a synonym

Comment: @Tshepang Why retag it? Merging the tags would actually be the best course, then burnination.

Comment: @hichris123 I would prefer that option if the smaller of the tags had a lot more Questions than [tag:downloading] has.

Comment: The tags are now synonymized, feel free to post a new burnination request for the tag.

Answer (score 47):

I think you are tackling the issue the wrong way, there are no experts at either download or downloading (if there are, my career selection sucked), so both needs to go.

Counterproposal: burninate both downloading and download.

Comment: "No experts" is undefined therefore meaningless, and even if it was defined it's not the reason to get rid of a tag.

Comment: @slugster "**Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer** by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories. " do this tag fulfill that condition? Do it sort anything? Do "help you identify questions that are interesting or relevant to" anyone? I fail to see any reason why it should stay.

Comment: I agree with Braiam's proposal. When would you say you are a download expert? You would say networking expert, perhaps, or something along that line.

Comment: But sometimes listing your issue as a networking issue, may be a little to broad. Maybe there is someone who is more of an expert in specifically downloading...

Comment: @Jeremy downloading is just the act of transferring data of a from a remote network to your own, networking is specific.

Comment: @Amicable Ok I see. I never really thought about it like that.

Comment: there is download-web-files. blarg